# How to exit browser in R when using swirl() package usng R3.3.2

Tags: r, debugging, browser, swirl

I'm using swirl package (v3.3.3) and debugging "ls" function. And can't seem to get out of the browser. None of 'f', 'c', 'C', 'Q', 'q' seem to be helping me. I tried some combinations, but no luck. Using Q exits swirl package. But when I get into swirl again, it throws the browser back at me.
Please help me how to get out.

Answer (score 0):

Typing `nxt()` will exit the `play()` mode and bring you back to the `swirl()` tutorial. If you are trying to quit `swirl()` altogether and go back into normal `R`, just type `bye()`. Typing `info()` brings up a list of all the possible options.

Answer (score 0):

skip() works well too. It will move you through the lessons and give you the answers, so that if you need to sumbit a token at the end it will get you there.